# HTML Form, Validate & Preview in same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

i just built up a simple contact form and i am facing a problem  previewing it in same file and same page .

In this coding, there is 3 types of division  :

1. HTML Form
2. php validation
3. 2nd variant page to be a preview page; trigger after complete the validation

**The file name form.php .**

Here is the code :

```
   <?php
// validate data
$fnameErr = $lnameErr  = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {    
  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
      $fnameErr = "First name is required";
    }
elseif (preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST["fname"]) === 0) {
  $fnameErr = "First name must contain letters and spaces only";
}
else  {
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
}
    if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
        $lnameErr = "Last name is required";
    }
elseif (preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST["lname"]) === 0) {
  $lnameErr = "Last name must contain letters and spaces only";
}
    else {
        $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    }

   }



?>
   // 1st variant that will be form 
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #99FF99;
}
.style3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
}
.style4 {
    color: #0000FF;
}
.style5 {
    text-align: center;
}
.style6 {
    background-color: #FEFECB;
}
.error {
    color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="25" align="center" class="style1">
    <tr>
    <form method="POST"
 action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">     <td>
        <div class="style3">
            :: <strong><span class="style4">STUDENT INFORMATION</span> </strong>
            ::</div>
        <table style="width: 100%">
                    </table>
        <table style="width: 100%" class="style6" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 30px; width: 106px">First Name&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 14px; height: 30px;" class="style5"><strong>:</strong></td>
                <td style="width: 204px; height: 30px;"><input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fname);?>">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="height: 30px"><span class="error"><?php echo $fnameErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 106px">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 14px" class="style5"><strong></strong></td>
                <td style="width: 204px">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 106px">Last Name</td>
                <td style="width: 14px" class="style5"><strong>:</strong></td>
                <td style="width: 204px"><input name="lname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lname);?>"></td>
                <td><span class="error"><?php echo $lnameErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
        </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>


//--------this code below i want to become as preview page , 2nd variant page that will be switch on after validation complete ---------
<body>

<table style="width: 600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="25" align="center" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="style3">
        :: <strong><span class="style4">STUDENT INFORMATION</span> </strong>
        ::</div>
      <table style="width: 100%">
      </table>
      <table style="width: 100%" class="style6" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <td style="height: 27px; width: 106px">First Name&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="width: 14px; height: 27px;" class="style5"><strong>:</strong></td>
          <td style="width: 204px; height: 27px;"><?php echo $fname ?> </td>
          <td style="height: 27px"><span class="error"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 106px">&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="width: 14px" class="style5"><strong></strong></td>
          <td style="width: 204px">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 106px">Last Name</td>
          <td style="width: 14px" class="style5"><strong>:</strong></td>
          <td style="width: 204px"> <?php echo $lname ?></td>
          <td><span class="error"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 106px">&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="width: 14px" class="style5"><strong></strong></td>
          <td style="width: 204px">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 106px">&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="width: 14px" class="style5"><strong></strong></td>
          <td style="width: 204px">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

, 
Any feedback is really appreciated , thank you!

Comment: What kind of feedback are you looking for? As it is your code is just missing an `if` and an `else`. That's pretty much all you need to add.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you post your code here and not only provide us with a link.

Comment: maybe this should be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: actually it was my first time, thanks for comment, i've update it

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your:

```
<form method="POST"
 action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

to

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

2nd point - you have to decide  what is your condition to show 2nd variant of page.

For example:

```
if (isset($POST['fname']) && $_POST['fname']==$fname 
    && isset($POST['lname']) && $_POST['lname']==$lname ) {$setPageVariant = 'noform';} else {$setPageVariant = 'form';};
```

put this line right before html part start (line #27-28)

3rd. In your html replace:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

with

```
<?php if ($setPageVar=='form') { ?> <form method="POST" action=""> <?php } ?>
```

and same condition but with else for inputs. replace for example:

```
<input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fname);?>">
```

with

```
<?php if ($setPageVar=='form') { ?>
    <input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fname);?>">
<?php } else { echo $fname; } ?>
```

I hope you've got an idea and can go ahead in your project :-) Good luck!

Comment: hi , thanks for your feedback , i really appreciated , i'm want to know how to switch or toggle the 2nd variant page in same page , some say using ajax wrap ,some say using javascript , i really don't know how to do it . Di you have any idea ?

Comment: I have answered to your question already, did you implement my code changes?

Comment: yes , i got boolean error , never mind, maybe its due to my xampp version

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\demo-borang.php on line 27

Comment: check my updates answer - there were some typos : `    if (isset($POST['fname']) && $_POST['fname']==$fname 
        && isset($POST['lname']) && $_POST['lname']==$lname ) {$setPageVariant = 'noform';} else {$setPageVariant = 'form';};
`